# Why is my CSV file not returning all of the data points?

Tags: python, csv, replace

```
G = open('Moving_Average.csv','r').read().replace(",",'\n')
F = open('Moving_Average_Adjustment.csv','w')
F.write(G)
F.close
```

Moving_Average.csv has a total of 2497 data points.

Moving_Average_Adjustment.csv has a total of 2299 data points.

I am unsure why it is skipping the final `200 data points, everything up to the first missing data point is exactly the same.

Comment: It's recommended that you use Python's [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module for reading and writing to csv files. Other methods can sometimes lead to data being misread or lost.

Comment: How can I replace it the same way as above?

Comment: What would happen if there's a comma in one of your data points? Use the CSV module. It's there for a reason.

Comment: I understand that could be an issue, however I know for a fact that I don't have any commas in this data set or any of the ones that I will be using this program on.

Comment: Looks to me like you're not closing the file, you're just saying the name of the `close` method.  Does it change if you use `F.close()`?

Comment: @DSM that fixed it from what I can see. I'll have to check other ones but thanks.